# C++: File_Error: Program returns a file error even though the file exists in directory

Tags: c++, linux, vim

I'm working on an assignment, and one of my defined error codes is FILE_ERROR(4), where the file does not exist in the directory.

Below is the troublesome code:

```
ifstream drawerState("drawer");

getline(drawerState, line);    //line is empty string

if(drawerState.good())
{
    //file parsing and variable assignment
}
else
    FILE_ERROR();
```

I'm very confused as to why this is happening. Not only does this particular sub-command depend on another one to work (other command creates the file), but if I ls or vim, the file clearly exists. The only change I made between edits was adding extra parsings, but I don't know why that would affect the state of the file existing.

For clarity, I do not have access to C++ 11 as I'm working on an older linux emulator.

If you need me to post extra information, please let me know. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your program is probably starting with its current/working directory set somewhere unexpected. Using relative file paths is often dangerous because of this possibility.

Comment: The thing that's really confusing me is that the program was working fine right up until the point I started adding more code/editing. Why would the file path somehow change?

Comment: Use `getcwd` and print out the current directory, maybe it will give a clue.

Comment: Where is getcwd located? I cannot use Boost libraries as the shell I'm working in is older and doesn't even have c++ 11

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd <- `getcwd()` comes from POSIX. Not boost.